# $X$ be compact, $U$ open and $f: X → \mathbb{R}$ continuous such that $f (X) \subset U$. $n> n_0 ⇒ f_n (X) \subset U.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be compact, $U$ open and $f: X → \mathbb{R}$ continuous such that $f (X) \subset U$. If a sequence of functions
$f_n: X → \mathbb{R}$ converge uniformly to $f: X → \mathbb{R}$, prove that there is $n_0 \in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$n> n_0 ⇒ f_n (X) \subset U.$$

I am completely stuck in that statement. I tried to use the fact that

A sequence of functions $f_n: X → \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly
convergent if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence.

But I didn't find any better way to prove this statement. Does someone know how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(X)$ is a  compact set disjoint from $U^{c}$. Hence, there is  a positive distance $r$ between these two. Choose $n_0$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| <r$ for all $x$ if $n >n_0$. Can you now show that $f_n(x) \in U$ for all $x$ if $n >n_0$?

Comment: Why is there a positive distance $r$ between $f$ and $f_n$?

Comment: @Manatee : There is a positive distance between $f(X)$ and $U^c$, not between $f_n$ and $f$. In other words, since $f(X) \subseteq U$, $f(X) \cap U^c = \varnothing$, and since $f(X)$ is compact and $U^c$ is closed, $\inf_{x \in X, y \in U^c} d(f(x), y) > 0$. This is because if it were zero, the sequential compactness of $f(X)$ and the closedness of $U^c$ would allow you to find a point in the intersection.

Comment: I got this now. But unfortunately I still couldn't understand the idea of this demonstration. :(

Comment: @Manatee Basicaly, $f_n(x) \in U$ is equivalent to $f_n(x)$ 'staying away' form $U^{c}$

Comment: Right. $f(X)\cap U^C=\emptyset$ and by this argument, there is a $r>0$ and $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$n>n_0\rightarrow |f_n(x)-f(x)|<r,\forall x\in X.$$ 
So, what I just need to do now is to show that $f_n(x)\not\in U^C,\forall x\in X$. However, I have no idea where can i show this from. :(

Comment: @Manatee If $f_n(x) \in U^{c}$ then $r=d(f(X),U^{c}) \leq |f_n(x)-f(x)| <r$ which is a  contradiction. [ If $A$ abd $B$ are two sets of real numbers then $d(A,B) \leq |a-b|$ whenever $a \in A$ and $b \in B$].

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think I am abusing your goodwill, but my goal is to understand this demonstration step by step. I just haven't figured out the reason for this yet:
$$d(f(X),U^C)\leq |f_n(x)-f(x)|$$
Is it because $f_n(x)\subset U^C$? Why is $f_n(x)$ a subset of the complement of U? I think I am missing something.

Comment: @Manatee We are assuming that $f_n(x) \in U^{c}$ and arriving at a  contradiction. [The  infimum of any set of real numbers is less than or equal to any member of the set. $d(f(X),U^{c})$ is, by definition, the infimum of the number $d(y,z)$ over all $y \in f(X)$ and $z \in U^{c}$. Choose $y=f(x)$ and $z=f_n(x)$].

Comment: OMG. I got it. I totally got it. Now it's just for my curiosity. Is there any way to show that the distance between $f (X) $ and $ U ^ C$ is greater than zero, in a different way that Patrick did? just using the fact that $f (X)$ and $U ^ C$ are closed?

Comment: @Manatee Unfortunately the distance between two disjoint closed sets can be $0$. Compactness of one of the sets is essential.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to paint a picture which will hopefully give you some intuition. If you don't know about metric spaces, just read $|x-y|$ anywhere I wrote $d(x,y)$.

In a metric space $X$, when $K \subseteq X$ is compact and $U \subseteq X$ is open, one can show that the "inflation of $K$ of radius $r$" is contained in $U$ for small enough $r$. This set is defined as
$$
\mathrm{infl}(K,r) = \{ y \in X \, | \, \exists x \in K \, \text{such that} \, d(x,y) < r \}. 
$$
So basically the result is that if $K$ is compact and $U$ is open, then $\mathrm{infl}(K,r) \subseteq U$ for some small enough $r$. The proof by contradiction is fairly simple: since $U$ is open, $X \setminus U$ is closed, and $K \cap (X \setminus U) = \varnothing$. This implies that
$$
\inf_{x \in K, y \in X \setminus U} d(x,y) > 0.
$$
To see this, suppose this infimum is zero. Pick a sequence $(x_n,y_n) \in K \times (X \setminus U)$ satisfying $d(x_n,y_n) < \frac 1n$. Since $K$ is compact, the sequence $x_n$ admits a convergent subsequence; without loss of generality, we may assume $x_n$ is convergent since $\frac 1n$ is decreasing. So $x_n \to x \in K$, and since $d(x_n,y_n) < \frac 1n$, we also have $y_n \to x \in X \setminus U$ because $X \setminus U$ is closed. This contradicts that $K \cap (X \setminus U) = \varnothing$, so we must conclude that the infimum is positive.

Let $r$ be this infimum. By definition of the infimum, this implies $\mathrm{infl}(K,r) \cap (X \setminus U) = \varnothing$ because if $y \in X \setminus U$ would satisfy $d(x,y) < r$ for some $x \in X$, this would contradict the definition of our infimum above. It follows that $\mathrm{infl}(K,r) \subseteq U$ for some $r > 0$.

Now that we got this "metric space fact" out of the way, since $X$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, $f(X)$ is compact and contained in $U$, so we can choose some $r > 0$ small enough such that $\mathrm{infl}(f(X), r) \subseteq U$. The fact that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ is equivalent to saying that under the supremum norm
$$
\|g\|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in X} |g(x)|,
$$
we have $\|f_n - f\|_{\infty} \to 0$. Choose $n_0$ large enough so that $\|f_n - f\|_{\infty} < r$ for all $n \ge n_0$. I claim that $\|f_n - f\|_{\infty} < r$ implies $f_n(X) \subseteq \mathrm{infl}(f(X), r)$, which is itself a subset of $U$, completing the proof.

But this is clear: if $x \in X$, since $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \le \|f_n-f\|_{\infty} < r$, it follows that $f_n(x) \in \mathrm{infl}(f(X), r)$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Wow, this is totally insane! This is brilliant. I partially understood the reasoning. I didn't fully understand it because it is much more advanced than I study.

Comment: @Manatee: Haha I don't think it's insane, it's just a bit more abstract! You can get used to it. But I thought that the picture of "inflating $f(X)$ by the radius $r$" was the key piece of intuition behind this exercise, so I wanted to point it out.

Comment: All right. Thank you for your attention and your intelligence. :)

Comment: @Manatee : Feel free to ask if some parts deserve more explanation